# Picard-Lindelöf global or local L continuity

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If we have a function in an *unbounded* interval, can we apply the Picard-Lindelöf theorem and show Lipschitz continuity **locally**? Or Picard-Lindelöf is applied only for global Lipschitz continuity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picard-Lindelöf is only ever about **local** existence and uniqueness for a solution of a differential equation.  The hypotheses (in particular Lipschitz continuity) are only needed locally.  Of course if you do happen to have global Lipschitz, you also have it locally.  You may be able to prove global existence of the solution if you have suitable estimates (e.g. with Grönwall's inequality), but that's not Picard-Lindelöf.

Comment: Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality